# How to use sp_executesql to avoid SQL Injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection, sp-executesql

In the below sample code, Table Name is an input parameter. In this case, how can I avoid SQL injection using `sp_executesql`. Below is the sample code, I am trying to use `sp_executesql`to avoid it but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to correct it?

```
ALTER PROC Test @param1  NVARCHAR(50), 
                 @param2  INT, 
                 @tblname NVARCHAR(100) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000) 

      SET @sql= N'  select * from ' + @tblname 
                + ' where name= @param1 and id= @param2'; 

      PRINT @sql 

      EXEC Sp_executesql 
        @sql, 
        N'@param1 nvarchar(50), @param2 int', 
        @param1, 
        @param2; 
  END 

EXEC Test 
  'John', 
  2, 
  ' emp; delete from emp where id = 567; select * from emp '
```

Output: 
Print message:

```
select * from  emp; delete from emp where id = 567; select * from emp  where name= @param1 and id= @param2;
```

All the input parameters are exactly substituted and one row is deleted.
Please let me know how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Try enclosing the table in `[]`

Comment: Still vulnerable: `emp]; delete from emp where id = 567; select * from [emp`

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. How do we handle such scenario?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can enclose the table name in `[]`

```
SET @sql= N'  select * from [' + @tblname + '] where name= @param1 and id= @param2';
```

However, if you use a two-part naming convention e.g `dbo.tablename`, you have to add additional parsing, since `[dbo.tablename]` will result to:

> Invalid object name [dbo.tablename].

You should parse it so that it'll be equal to `dbo.[tablename]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could first check if the parameter value is indeed a table name:

```
ALTER PROC Test @param1  NVARCHAR(50), 
             @param2  INT, 
             @tblname NVARCHAR(100) 
AS 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000) 

  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'u' AND name = @tblname)
  BEGIN
      SET @sql= N'  select * from ' + @tblname 
                + ' where name= @param1 and id= @param2'; 

      PRINT @sql 

      EXEC Sp_executesql 
        @sql, 
        N'@param1 nvarchar(50), @param2 int', 
        @param1, 
        @param2; 
  END
END
```

If the passed value is not a table name your procedure won't do anything; or you could change it to throw an error. This way you're safe if the parameter contains a query.